# Android Special Characters

Tags: android, validation, special-characters, android-edittext, symbols

Hi i need to validate an edit text box which user need to enter his height, I need to allow the user only this two symbols (" ') ex: 5'11". I want to restrict user entering other special characters, how to restrict, need a help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set following property to your edittext

```
android:digits="'&quot;1234567890"
```

Comment: hi i tried passing characters its not working, is that possible to include " and ' inside android:digits